# Can I Use a Dummy Variable in Quadratic form in lm() in R?

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data, ggplot2

I'm trying to replicate models published in [The Age-Productivity Gradient: Evidence from a Sample of F1 Drivers](http://www.csef.it/WP/wp226.pdf) and am stumbling at first hurdle over a line "the baseline specification contains a quadratic in age and drivers dummies".

I can get quadratic `age` (a numerical var) and linear `name` dummy (a factor in the original dataset) with the following construction:

```
lm(pos ~ name + I(age) +I((age)^2),data=ergastData)
```

but I get an error on

```
lm(pos ~ name + I(name^2) + I(age) +I((age)^2),data=ergastData)
```

because `name` is a factor and squaring it is not meaningful?

So how can I get a quadratic term for the dummy variable?

*(I'm not a statistician.. I assume this is a meaningful thing to do and my interpretation of the original paper is correct!)*

As an extension of this question, with ggplot2, I can chart the individual `name` model results using:

```
g = ggplot(egastdata, aes(x=age,y=pos,col=name))
g = g + stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ I(x) +I((x)^2)) +geom_point()
g
```

This seems to group on `name` and presumably generate separate models for each driver (i.e. a set of distinct `age` coefficients for each driver).  How would I use `ggplot` to chart the result of a single set of `age` coefficients and then separate `name` dummy variable coefficients (both linear in `name` and quadratic)? (That is, I want a single model around `age` with a separate coefficients around `name` for each driver.) Would the age coefficients be the same as if I ran the model over the whole set of driver data without distinguishing drivers?

Comment: Read the "and" like "plus". They include a variable $age^2$ plus a variable $driver dummy$. That is, "the baseline specification contains (a quadratic in age) + (drivers dummies)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it seems you misinterpreted the sentence.  Squaring a factor is not meaningful.  The paper includes a quadratic term for age.  There is also a dummy variable for the driver.